# Update column value of one table based on values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables...

```
        table_x                          table_y
| location | latitude |  | location | min_latitude | max_latitude |
| -------- | -------- |  | -------- | ------------ | ------------ |
|          |   41.5   |  |  point_x |     41.0     |     42.0     |
```

How do I set `table_x.location` to `table_y.location` if `table_x.latitude` is in between `table_y.min_latitude` and `table_y.max_latitude`? I tried the code below but it cannot recognize `table_y`.

```
UPDATE table_x
SET table_x.location = table_y.location
WHERE table_x.latitude BETWEEN table_y.min_latitude AND table_y.max_latitude
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, table_y comes from nowhere.
Try this:

```
UPDATE table_x x
JOIN table_y y
ON x.latitude BETWEEN y.min_latitude AND y.max_latitude
SET x.location = y.location
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I would have never thought of doing "ON x.latitude BETWEEN y.min_latitude AND y.max_latitude".

Comment: @gaphalpa You're welcome. Also, you can update only those registers with empty location by adding: WHERE x.location = '' OR x.location = NULL

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the second table

**But** as many rows can be selected for update, you should test this prior of running the query

```
UPDATE table_x,table_y
SET table_x.location = table_y.location
WHERE table_x.latitude BETWEEN table_y.min_latitude AND table_y.max_latitude
```

Comment: This worked too! Thank you!